# Google OAuth2 returns "unsupported_grant_type" via cURL (PHP)

Tags: php, curl, google-api

I want to get data about google account. I use next code:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token',
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        'Cache-Control: no-cache',
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    ],
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => [
        'code' => $code,
        'client_id' => '{MY_CLIENT_ID}',
        'client_secret' => '{MY_CLIENT_SECRET}',
        'redirect_uri' => '{SOME_URL}'
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    ]
));

$result = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);
```

In result I get next error:

```
{
    "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
    "error_description": "Invalid grant_type: "
}
```

I use instructions from this:

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect

Variable `$code` and another data are valid! Because I try to send request via "PostMan" and there I get correct result.

Tell me please, where I have mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Try to do that in this way:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token',
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query([
        'code' => $code,
        'client_id' => '{MY_CLIENT_ID}',
        'client_secret' => '{MY_CLIENT_SECRET}',
        'redirect_uri' => '{SOME_URL}'
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    ]),
));
```

BTW, you can debug curl requests using

```
CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! I tried your way and I got same error... But! When I tried different "redirect_uri", I solved my trouble. And I don't understand, why not each URI I can use in params? They all added in list of my Google App, but only one (not first!) from 6 URI is valid! What I missed around settings my Google App?

Comment: I found solution. BTW, need set "redirect_uri" same as URL which set in the first request which getting "code". That's all. P.S.: Maybe I missed this note from documentation... :(

Answer (score 0):

I was doing this in c# and think my issue could be related. When specifying the redirect_url or any other string, make sure you escape the URI otherwise it will mess up the post request. This is because the request is sent using application/x-www-form-urlencoded type.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error message. After some research, I came to know that I am creating Code using **access_type = 'offline'** and this is a problem.

So I have removed this parameter from my request and generated new code without using **access_type = 'offline'**.

The problem is solved.

Please try or let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: if that works that would be strange thing but that will still not be the root cause, what if we actually want offline access_type and still want it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your authorization code has not expired. Because that was what I was doing wrong and i got the same error response. I was actually testing my code by sending an old authorization code. As soon as I tied my code to the actual oauth workflow, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

The above code is missing a comma at the end of this line:

```
'redirect_uri' => '{SOME_URL}'
```

Full code should be:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token',
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        'Cache-Control: no-cache',
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    ],
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => [
        'code' => $code,
        'client_id' => '{MY_CLIENT_ID}',
        'client_secret' => '{MY_CLIENT_SECRET}',
        'redirect_uri' => '{SOME_URL}',
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    ],
));

$result = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);
```