# https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token always returns unsupported_grant_type / Invalid grant_type on Android

Tags: google-oauth

I have an Ionic app which logs in users using Google auth. It passes an id_token and access_token to a node server which then uses the id_token to verify the user, and the access_token to make calls to the user's Google account.

When the Ionic app is used from a browser, it uses gapi to log the user in and get the tokens, which works fine. For iOS and Android, it uses the official Cordova plugin (cordova-plugin-googleplus).

For iOS, the plugin always returns both tokens, and all is good. For Android, no access_token is ever returned. I therefore followed the instructions to get a serverAuthCode instead, which also works. Exchanging the serverAuthCode for an access_token is where the problem lies.

The official Google instructions provide the sample request

```
POST /oauth2/v4/token HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

code=4/P7q7W91a-oMsCeLvIaQm6bTrgtp7&
client_id=your_client_id&
client_secret=your_client_secret&
redirect_uri=https://oauth2.example.com/code&
grant_type=authorization_code
```

I supplied the client_id and client_secret used in the call to get the serverAuthCode. I verified that the serverAuthCode I am sending looks correct, starting with "4/". The redirect_uri is a bit of a mystery. I tried everything I could think of, including Authorized redirect URIs associated with the client_id, null, the URI from the example, and many weird suggestions from the web. No matter what, whether from the app or from SoapUI, I receive

```
{
 "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
 "error_description": "Invalid grant_type: "
}
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43408821/google-oauth2-returns-unsupported-grant-type-via-curl-php) seems to say that the redirect_uri must match that used in the call to get the serverAuthCode. This is however set by the plugin, and looking at its code I cannot find it being set anywhere.

So my question is: can any one please tell me how to get an access_token on Android? If the above post is correct, is there a way to find out what redirect_uri is used by the plugin? Or is there another way entirely to get the access_token? [This issue](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/issues/398) offers a hack to get the plugin to return an access_token directly, but also implies that Google is deprecating in favor of serverAuthCode, so it seems best to get the access_code from the serverAuthCode.

(Update: the workaround above also did not work in our case, so we seem to be stuck at this point)

Comment: Google instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#exchange-authorization-code). Anyone from Google monitoring this tag?

Answer (score 0):

After days of trying things, we finally found that the encoding of the post wasn't correct. Needless to say, some kind of info in the error response would be helpful -- especially in this case since in testing various body formats, it was clear that the parameters were being recognized, yet nevertheless an error was being returned.

Still no idea why on Android the `access_token` suddenly stopped being returned, making this call necessary in the first place. Hopefully this will help others!

Comment: Can you please elaborate, encoding of what wasn't correct. I am also stuck in this issue.

Comment: We had recently switched to HttpClient, and the body and options weren’t using the correct objects; the proper setup was
~~~
 let search = new URLSearchParams();
        search.set('code', authCode);
        search.set('grant_type', 'authorization_code');
// ...
        let body = search.toString();
        let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        let options: any = { headers: headers };
~~~

Answer (score 0):

I've suffered from the same problem, and I found that after re-authentication and got a new code to getting try it again, the ID token responded properly.